# Android : For call and send SMS Intent need to add permission?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, call

I'm working on Call and SMS Intent while user click on call and SMS button.

Question:

**1) Need to add permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?**

**2) Need to code for runtime permission also?**

I write code for **call intent** is below:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + driverMobileNo));
                startActivity(intent);
```

**SMS intent**

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:"+ driverMobileNo));
            it.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");
            startActivity(it);
```

Above code working fine (tested in Oreo 8.0 version) without adding permission in AndroidManifest.xml and also runtime.

Comment: permission is not required for the above code

Comment: Learn explicit intent vs implicit Intent

Comment: yes @VivekMishra thanks for reply, is there any document for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this code without any permission:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));     
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message); 
startActivity(intent);
```

For the call, you can use this without any permission:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:phoneNumber"))
startActivity(intent);
```

You don't need any permission as the user actually make the call, you just redirect him to the phone app. If you want to make the phone call directly through your app, you have to use `ACTION_CALL` instead of `ACTION_DIAL` and add the permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: and what about call?

Comment: Edited my last post.

Answer (score 0):

For sms you can write

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"+phoneNumber)); // This ensures only SMS apps respond
intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

and for call you can use this intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```